# toastr js plugin and css color change

Tags: css, base64, toastr

I am using the toastr js plugin - [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) - and have made a css color change, however, I do not know how to go about creating the correct png/base64 part?

**Original :**

```
.toast-info {
  background-color: #2f96b4;
}

#toast-container > .toast-info {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
```

**I have changed this color to :**

```
.toast-info {
  background-color: #3276b1;
}
```

I actually contacted the github location awhile back and never got a response other than contact SO haha.  For sake of having things correct I would like to make sure the base64 part corresponds to the new color.

**EDIT - further info :**

In response to the answer below.  I believe you are incorrect.  Correct me if I am wrong, but the background-image is basically a backup so it shows correctly in all browsers and does indeed reflect the color.  Based on your comments... if that were true then this background image would not be needed at all and, if anything, would be the same for each color.  As you can see this is not the case.

Here is the full css including my added info2 with the new color.  So, basically the question holds.  How can I create the correct base64 background image with my new color?

```
#toast-container > .toast-info {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-info2 {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-error {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-success {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADsSURBVEhLY2AYBfQMgf///3P8+/evAIgvA/FsIF+BavYDDWMBGroaSMMBiE8VC7AZDrIFaMFnii3AZTjUgsUUWUDA8OdAH6iQbQEhw4HyGsPEcKBXBIC4ARhex4G4BsjmweU1soIFaGg/WtoFZRIZdEvIMhxkCCjXIVsATV6gFGACs4Rsw0EGgIIH3QJYJgHSARQZDrWAB+jawzgs+Q2UO49D7jnRSRGoEFRILcdmEMWGI0cm0JJ2QpYA1RDvcmzJEWhABhD/pqrL0S0CWuABKgnRki9lLseS7g2AlqwHWQSKH4oKLrILpRGhEQCw2LiRUIa4lwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-warning {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}

.toast {
  background-color: #030303;
}
.toast-info {
  background-color: #3276b1;
}
.toast-info2 {
  background-color: #2f96b4;
}
.toast-error {
  background-color: #bd362f;
}
.toast-success {
  background-color: #51a351;
}
.toast-warning {
  background-color: #f89406;
}
```

Comment: Nobody changed colors with this plugin before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image is not the background color. If you want to change the color, you already have it with background-color. If you want to change the background image, then you can set the url or base64. If you want an easy way to convert to base64,

- use Visual Studio
- install Web Essentials plug in
- set the url to the file
- right click on the url and Web Essentials menu will let you convert to base64

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I believe this is not the case.  See my edit above.

Comment: the background image is the icon. not the color. the icon is error, success, info, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I use custom toast with this css and javascript

```
toastr.success("text", "title", {"iconClass": 'customer-info'});
```

css:

```
/* icon */
#toast-container > .customer-info {            
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```